# Android - What data structure to store video subtitles to get them in O(1) time

Tags: android, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap, android-mediaplayer

I am playing a video in my application and I have to show subtitles on top of that. subtitles are in a separate smi file which is some sort of XML markup that provides subtitle information. the subtitle file looks something like this:

```
.
.
.
<sync start=104600>
            <P Class=GBR><i></i><span ID=style1_0><i>Born of cold and winter air</i> </span><br><i></i><span ID=style1_0><i>and mountain rain combining.</i> </span></P>
        </sync>
        <sync start=107080>
            <P Class=MYS>&nbsp;<br></P>
        </sync>
        <sync start=107200>
            <P Class=MYS><i></i><span ID=style2_0><i>...serta hujan di pergunungan.</i> </span></P>
        </sync>
        <sync start=110840>
            <P Class=MYS>&nbsp;<br></P>
            <P Class=GBR>&nbsp;<br></P>
        </sync>
        <sync start=111160>
            <P Class=SIM>&nbsp;<br></P>
        </sync>
        <sync start=111480>
            <P Class=GBR><i></i><span ID=style1_0><i>This icy force</i> </span><br><i></i><span ID=style1_0><i>both foul and fair...</i> </span></P>
        </sync>
.
.
.
.
```

the `start` is the time in milliseconds when to show the subtitle on top of the video. Now I am parsing the using regex and creating a `ArrayList` of `SubtitleChunk` which contains the startTime and content associated with it.

```
class SubtitleChunk {
    long startTime;
    String content;
}
```

Now while showing the video I have started a separate thread which I am using get the subtitle from array and show it. Following is the logic

```
public void run() {
    while (!isFinished_) {
            if (subtitleContent != null && subtitleContent.content_ != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    SubtitleChunk subChunk1 = null;
                    SubtitleChunk subChunk2 = null;
                    try {
                        subChunk1 = subtitleContent.content_.get(i);
                        subChunk2 = subtitleContent.content_.get(i + 1);

                        long cTime = moviePlayer_.getCurrentTimeMillis();
                        if (cTime > subChunk1.startTime && (subChunk2 == null || cTime < subChunk2.startTime)) {
                            currentSub = subChunk1.content;
                            currentChunk = subChunk1;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        DebugUtil.printLogException(VIEW_LOG_TAG, e);
                        currentSub = "";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                currentSub = "";
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (moviePlayer_.isPlaying()) {
                    subtitleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentSub));
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am running a loop on the ArrayList and comparing the time of the subtitles with the `moviePlayer_.getCurrentTimeMillis()` which I feel is too expensive. and subtitles are lagging and not in sync with the video.

All above was the explaination of the issue. and Now the question.. How can I improve it? to get the Subtitle for a specific time in O(1) time.

## EDITED

I went with Interval Trees, thats what I needed to put the subtitles in: I got it from here: https://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation

Comment: It really depends.  Do you need random access, or only sequential?  Will you be searching for exact times, or do you need to find near matches (for example, may you need to check for time t=1000 and get a subtitle at time t=950 or 1050)?  Also, do you really need O(1) or is O(log(n)) good enough?  Accepting log(n) would make a near match algorithm much easier.

Comment: @GabeSechan anything will work as long as it is not just running a for loop in a while loop to get the subtitles content and traverse though the whole array again and again. and the subtitles are going to be sequential as i am getting them based on the current video time. I have also updated the subtitle getting logic, please check that.

Comment: I agree with Gabe. But looking at O(1), requirement, why not use `Map<VideoId, Map<TimeFromSubTitleChunk, SubTitleChunk>>`. Here VideoId, is just an Id to identify the Video. So, if you dont care about that, then just `Map<TimeFromSubtitleChunk, SubtitleChunk>`.

Comment: @vijar : i though about it too, but the problem it that the loop is not running at 1 / ms speed, so let say i save  `<34566, "subtitle">` int the `hashmap` and in the while loop `mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime() is 34569`, the I will not be getting the subtitle.

Comment: So essentially you want a range Query. If yes, then I would suggest to use TreeMap.subMap (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap(K, K))

Comment: @vijar : sorry I am lost, can you please explain how this will help me with some kind of example or something?

Comment: If you don't know the exact subtitle you are looking for, you will never get o(1)… you have to SEARCH for it in some form…

Comment: Sorry ignore my prev commit. `startTime` is relative to the beginning of the video. So, one know where is one in video relative to the start. If the current relative time lies in certain range, then I can get the subtitle. I am not sure if any data-structure from Java library can be helpful. Take a look at Segment Tree/Interval Tree. It will give you more insight.Take a look at http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Segment_Trees. I hope this might be helpful. The idea is to preprocess your SMI file

Comment: @vijar I looked into Segment Trees/Interval Trees/Range Trees and read a lot about all of them and finally went with Interval Tree. It is exactly what I needed. I got it from here: https://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation

Comment: @vijar can you put your comments as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: Just to get accepted :-) Lifted from my comment.

`startTime` is relative to the beginning of the video. So, one know where is one in video relative to the start. If the current relative time lies in certain range, then I can get the subtitle. I am not sure if any data-structure from Java library can be helpful. Take a look at [Segment Tree/Interval Tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Segment_Trees). It will give you more insight.I hope this might be helpful. The idea is to preprocess your SMI file